# Strange issue with CORS preflight request fails on IE 11

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, xmlhttprequest, cors

The problem, is that the the POST query fails on IE11, in all the other browsers it's seems working.

Lets describe the problem step by step:

1. XHR request from application to REST API.
2. Preflight OPTIONS request (request parameters are following)

> ```
> Accept:                         */*
> Origin:                         https://app.example.com
> Access-Control-Request-Method:  POST
> Access-Control-Request-Headers  content-type, accept
> :                               
> Accept-Encoding:                gzip, deflate
> User-Agent:                     Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
> Host:                           api.example.com
> Content-Length:                 0
> Connection:                     Keep-Alive
> Cache-Control:                  no-cache
> ```

2. preflight request response parameters are:

> ```
> X-Powered-By:                   Sugar
> Access-Control-Allow-Origin:    https://app.example.com
> Vary:                           Origin
> Access-Control-Allow-Credentia  true
> ls:                             
> Access-Control-Allow-Methods:   GET,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS
> Access-Control-Allow-Headers:   X-Requested-With,X-HTTP-Method-Override,Content-Type,Accept
> set-cookie:                     sugar.sid=s%Pb9OoTTPUkVw%2F2vUPoFMNG
>                                 LMXACSkQevo; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 15 Jan 2015 18:27:07 GMT; HttpOnly; Secure
> Date:                           Mon, 12 Jan 2015 18:27:07 GMT
> Connection:                     close
> ```

3. The real HTTP request after preflight request parameters:

> ```
> Accept:           application/json
> Content-Type:     application/json
> Referer:          https://app.example.com/
> Accept-Language:  en-US
> Origin:           https://app.example.com
> Accept-Encoding:  gzip, deflate
> User-Agent:       Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
> Host:             api.example.com
> Content-Length:   9
> Connection:       Keep-Alive
> Cache-Control:    no-cache
> Cookie:           sugar.sid=s%3A-%2FGF1YoFmRfmBsxK4vLBoGjY5NT0QoYvf5s;
> ```

4. Last response parameters:

> ```
> Content-Type:    application/json; charset=utf-8
> Content-Length:  72
> Vary:            Accept-Encoding
> Date:            Mon, 12 Jan 2015 18:27:07 GMT
> Connection:      close
> ```

5. Basically the response end with the IE error:  Origin: https://app.example.com not found in Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. Does the first request needs also the Access-**-Origin header, which seems to be missing.

Also followed the CORS flow chart for debugging problem, but I could not spot it http://www.html5rocks.com/static/images/cors_server_flowchart.png.

I am using Node.js Express server with the node-cors module + modified options.

Comment: the actual data-having response needs an ACAO header

Comment: Just tested this seems to be the issue, on Chrome the response has AC headers but on IE these have not set on the real data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using Fiddler to debug this issue on my site and got this message:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Date: Mon, 12 Sep 2016 19:40:20 GMT
Content-Length: 103

{"Message":"The collection of headers 'accept,if-modified-since,cache-control,pragma' is not allowed."}
```

[CORS the collection of headers accept,if-modified-since,cache-control,pragma](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICzgH.jpg)

So I just added to my web.api the list of missing headers to CORS.

I hope this helps to someone.